# Multiple Domains for 1 Website/Folder & CNAME

Tags: url, dns, https, cname

I have 2 domains which I would like to point to 1 website/location. The website is a brand created DAM with filecamp.com. So we have created testdam.filecamp.com (for example purposes). This will be shared with customers. There are to be 2 sections to this, and therefore it requires 2 domains (at least that you can see in the address bar). Inside you can create folders and separate themes/branding so this is perfect so far.

By default, Filecamp allows you to assign 1 primary custom domain which we've assigned as portal.example1.co.uk. So using that domain takes you to the DAM perfectly. SSL is assigned to that and the CNAME is assigned through this. However, as there are 2 sides and we require 2 domains, we are trying to also have portal.example2.co.uk go to the same website.

Filecamp doesn't offer many more DNS options, so it needs to be purely done elsewhere. We've tried to set up a CNAME for portal.example2.co.uk to go to portal.example1.co.uk but there's an SSL error (Certificate doesn't expect it - can't access the certificate).

In fairness, I did ask them about the possibility and they said that it may be possible but that nobody had managed it yet and they were skeptical.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance here, but what does DAM stand for?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister "Digital Asset Management". It's essentially a system for storing and distributing files. This can either be internally or externally - in this case, externally.